# Pidgin does not show all online buddies

Tags: pidgin, facebook

here is a photo of my problem:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/833/jmzy.jpg/

As you can see there are 4 buddies online but I only see one in the system tray.

What can I do that Pidgin shows every online buddy in the tray?

With best regards

New Ubuntu User

Answer (score 1):

That's the one you are currently chatting with, I can't imagine the message indicator was designed to show all contacts currently online.